# Where did Scar's other tattoo come from?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-brotherhood

In the 2009 anime, *Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood*, near the end of the series,

> Scar fights Wrath. During the battle, Scar surprises Wrath by using construction alchemy, revealing that he has a construction-based tattoo on his left arm.

Scar has not had this tattoo forever, though; in earlier scenes in the series, we can clearly see that Scar has only one tattoo on his body.

[image] [image]
*(Left: Scar, episode 22, no left tattoo. Right: Scar, episode 60, tattoo on his left.)*

Is it ever stated when Scar receives this tattoo? Who gave it to him?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although I can't remember it being stated, it is most likely, that he found the tattoo in his brothers notes and put it on his arm with the help of Dr. Marcoh.

> The tattoo was most likely one part of the preparations for the 'promised day' in episode 46 (2009), before Scar comes back with Marcoh from the negotiation with the Ishvals.